# MS Word 2021/365: Backspace and Return do not remove bullets/numbering

Tags: microsoft-word

I can select <BACKSPACE> and <ENTER> as much as I like, but the bullet remains (even if the list is forced Normal Style). It goes away with <DEL> but that removes the paragraph mark in front and doesn't work the same as <BACKSPACE> or <ENTER> would.

This issue has never occurred before for me, but I recently bought a new machine and upgraded to Office Pro Plus 2021 from Office Pro Plus 2016 and it has been happening since. It does not occur for me in Office 365 online or on Google Docs.

Since this started, I've combed the Microsoft Answers and Office forums, and it seems this issue has been sporadically occurring for years but MSFT MVPs have just been giving unhelpful solutions for as many years. I'm convinced there's a solution, but idk what it could be at this point. I've done everything short of reinstalling Office, which will have to be a last resort given how much I rely on it all day.

I've tried un/toggling:

- "Set left- and first-indent with tabs and backspaces"
- "Define styles based on your formatting"
- "Typing replaces selected text"
- "Use Normal style for bulleted or numbered lists"

I tried deleting Normal.dotm.

I tried reinstalling the English keyboard in Windows (US QWERTY).

Windows 11/22H2 and Office Pro Plus 2021 are fully up to date.

Comment: You've probably review this, but if not, see http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html. There are so many things that can change this in Word that I tend to simply rely on setting bullets using styles. It works 100% of the time. If you apply bullets using the button o the home tab, you can use the clear formatting button which returns you to the Normal style without indent or bullets.

Comment: Note that Drew's suggestion for deleting the Word key in Office in the Registry is much more drastic than uninstalling and reinstalling Office. It will wipe out a ton of your user settings. See my post on page 7 of this thread in the Microsoft Answers forum for a screenshot from the Registry Editor. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/unable-to-remove-bullets-by-using-backspace-or/326e88ca-24aa-4832-ac82-9de51987a1c7?LastReply=true#LastReply. To me, this would be analogous to using a chainsaw to get rid of an unsightly mole on my ear. I do not think I would do it.

Answer (score -1):

I did a ton of searching like you did, went through all the same generic "answers and fixes" that you did and only once I tried to open Word in safe mode did I start to get somewhere. The backspace and enter functions returned so I thought it must be an add-on or user setting. So to reset the user settings, I went into the registry, navigated to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word` and deleted the whole "Word" key and that fixed it.

Comment: To me, this would be analogous to using a chainsaw to get rid of an unsightly mole on my ear. I do not think I would do it. Deleting that entire key will take out much more than just this problem. See my screenshot at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/unable-to-remove-bullets-by-using-backspace-or/326e88ca-24aa-4832-ac82-9de51987a1c7?LastReply=true#LastReply  I suspect that just the Options or Data key would do the same thing. Backup registry settings before attempting anything like this. It is much easier to remove Add-In problems than such a complete wipe of user data.